# Bad interaction between defined macro, biblatex & URL reference

Tags: biblatex, macros, biber, incompatibility

I've been having trouble using pdflatex, biblatex & biber to compile a document.  I've narrowed it down to a macro I'm defining causing trouble with how biblatex processes a URL link.  If I take out the URL in the bibliography, or if I take out the definition of \sb, then the document compiles.

This is on Windows 10 using TeXLive from cygwin.

Document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{refs}

\def \sb {{\bf s}}

\title{A Paper}
\author{A. Author}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Ref \cite{FedRetirement2018}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file `refs.bib`:

```
@report{FedRetirement2018,
  author =   {Chien, Yi Li and Morris, Paul},
  title  =   {Many Americans Still Lack Retirement Savings},
  year   =   {2018},
  url    = {https://tinyurl.com/y5cvh89j}
}
```

Output from running `pdflatex; biber; pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Cygwin) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file test.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-01.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))))
No file test.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'FedRetirement2018' on page 1 undefined on input line 1
5.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 17.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 19194 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

biber test
INFO - This is Biber 2.16
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'refs.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'refs.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to test.bbl

pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Cygwin) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./test.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-2020-10-01.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))))
(./test.bbl)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of `.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.18 
     
?
```

Comment: well that happens if you use \def and redefine existing commands. The url package (used to typeset the url) uses `\sb` and don't like that you change its meaning.

Comment: Generally speaking, packages take pains to define macros in such a way that definitions in one's document don't interfere with the package.  I guess in LaTeX, there's no general way for a package to do this when it depends on another package.  The odd thing is, that I don't have this problem on Linux, so evidently, some versions of the url package use \sb & some don't, or some such thing.

It would be nice if there was a way to get around this, so I don't have to change the name of \sb & its usage in my doc.

Comment: this doesn't work this way in LaTeX. That's why the LaTeX command to define a command is `\newcommand` (which would warn you if you overwrite an existing command). If you use low-level commands like \def you are on your own. Side remark: \bf is deprecated and only defined in some classes, use \bfseries to make something bold.

Comment: `\sb` is not defined in a package it is defined in the latex format so by redefining it you break latex. You may sometimes get lucky and avoid an error but the system is basically broken. Conversely you have defined `\sb` in terms of `\bf` which is not defined by default in latex, so you are relying on the legacy definition added in article.cls for compatibility with latex2.09.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as solved?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I went ahead and posted an answer. If you want to write one up yourself, let me know and I will delete mine.

Comment: @moewe sorry I forgot, but it is fine if you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605153/bad-interaction-between-defined-macro-biblatex-url-reference#comment1517557_605153)

```
\def \sb {{\bf s}}
```

overwrite thes LaTeX kernel command `\sb` (defined as `\let\sb=_`) with a new definition. Because the code uses `\def` this happens without warning. (If the code had used the LaTeX convention `\newcommand` there would have been an error message telling us that `\sb` is already defined.)

Unfortunately, the `url` package relies on the definition of `\sb` from the LaTeX kernel and breaks with the new definition.

The best solution would be not to redefine `\sb`. Use a different name for your command. Most editors have a search-and-replace function so that you can easily switch to the new name in your source.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\bolds{\mathbf{s}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{ctan}
ipsum~\(\bolds^{2}=4\).

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you must absolutely stick with `\sb` as your macro name, you could try to make `url` work with a private copy of the kernel `\sb` as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\real@sb}{}
\let\real@sb=\sb
\def\set@mathnolig#1{\ifnum\mathcode`#1<32768
   \begingroup\lccode`\~`#1\lowercase{\endgroup
     \edef~}{\mathchar\number\mathcode`#1\real@sb{\/}}%
   \mathcode`#1=32768 \fi}
\makeatother

% this overrides the LaTeX kernel command
% avoid this if possible
% code assuming \sb has its usual definition
% may break 
\def \sb {\mathbf{s}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{ctan}
ipsum~\(\sb^{2}=4\).

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

but this only makes `url` work. Other code using `\sb` is still going to break. **Don't do this.**

---

Note that `\bf` is not actually defined in the LaTeX kernel and only provided by some document classes for backwards compatibility with LaTeX 2.09. In 1994 LaTeX2e was released which features a different font selection scheme. Use `\textbf{<text>}` for bold text and `\mathbf{<math>}` for bold maths. See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "fix url" ;-), url is certainly not broken here, and there is other code relying on \sb.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was wondering if this would sound wrong when I wrote it. Reworded. Thanks for the hint.